# How to put a visibility on all rows of a DataGridViewRow in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I am using the following code.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Visible = true;
}
```

However delayed, I wanted to know if you have any properties faster for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call datagridview.Invalidate() to have the draw happen.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a neat solution to your problem.  There is no property of the DataGridView that will make all rows visible/invisible with one line.  An idea would be to set the data source to null to hide the rows, then when you want to show it again, you can set the data source back to the original.  This is somewhat of a hack and not clean solution.

Alternatively, if it suits your needs, you can show/hide your entire DataGridView by setting the Visible property to true/false respectively.

Comment: Those two lines dealt with the lines you edited out.  That makes my answer much less substantial, but I will adjust it accordingly.